# Problems with .Insert and error saying Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
public static object Grp(List<GetQuestionsDTO> questions)
{
    var a = questions;
    var initialRow = new GetQuestionsDTO() { QuestionNumber = 0 };
    var c = a.Insert(0, initialRow);
}
```

I think I am doing everything right but I am getting an error saying:

> Error CS0815  Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

Can someone advise if they can see what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>.Insert` returns void (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx) so it has no value to assign, hence the error.

In your case, there's really no reason to get the return value, as you already have the object you're adding in the 'initialRow' variable.

Answer (score 3):

`a.Insert(0, initialRow)` is a `void` function, so you cannot assign `c` to it

Answer (score 0):

> The [`List<T>.Insert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx) method Inserts an element into the List
>   at the specified index.The zero-based index at which item should be inserted. Which will not return any value so that you cannot assign it as you did. I think this is what you actually tried to achieve;

```
public static object Grp(List<GetQuestionsDTO> questions)
{    
    questions.Insert(0, new GetQuestionsDTO() { QuestionNumber = 0 });
    return questions;
}
```

If you need the result in `c` you can do like this:

```
var a = questions;
var initialRow = new GetQuestionsDTO() { QuestionNumber = 0 };
a.Insert(0, initialRow);
var c =a;
```

Comment: what's `a` and what's the return type of `a.Insert()` in your static method?

Comment: sorry I was commenting your previous code, not your updated one.